# mysqli prepared statement with operator

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to do the following:

```
$search_query = "SELECT spec, title, quantity, location_to, location_from
                           FROM sm12761.assignments WHERE title = ? LIMIT 0,1 ";
```

But change it to WHERE title LIKE '&something%'

How would I do this ?

If some one could show me a refactored version of the query that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

append a `%` to your input string when calling `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`

Comment: You can't do that without altering the query.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are being precompiled on MySQL's side, so you need to change the query structure, to be able to use LIKE.

```
$search_query = "SELECT spec, title, quantity, location_to, location_from
                       FROM sm12761.assignments WHERE title LIKE ? LIMIT 0,1 ";
```

Comment: how would I add in a % though so its finding a wildcard

Comment: Like Dennis Haarbrink said above, you need to add it to your search string before you bind it to parameter.

Comment: Sorry just realised what he said.